# NoClassDefFoundError in Eclipse when adding project in build path

Tags: eclipse, exception

I am receiving an `NoClassDefFoundError` in Eclipse when I try to run my project.

My Project looks like this:

```
JavaProject: BulkAdmin
   - src
      - com.mycompany.bulkadmin.SDK.util
         - Login.java

Dynamic Web Project: JSPTesting
   - src
      - com.mycompany.bulkadmin.jspController
         - Controller.java
   - WebContent
      - index.html
      - execute.jsp
```

This is the control flow:

1. index.html loads
2. index.html has a form that redirects to execute.jsp
3. execute.jsp takes the info returned in the form and makes a static call to Login.java
4. execute.jsp prints the results of the call

Controller.java uses Login.java.  I was receiving compilation errors.  To resolve them I did this:

1. Right click on JSPTesting -> properties
2. Choose java build path on the left bar
3. Choose projects tab
4. Click add
5. Choose BulkAdmin (Project)

I am not sure why but now when I am getting a `NoClassDefFoundError`.  I have done some googling.  I think that this means that I have messed up my classpath somehow but I am not sure how to resolve this.

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/myCompany/bulkadmin/SDK/util/Login
    at com.myCompany.bulkadmin.jspController.Controller.process(Controller.java:44)
    at org.apache.jsp.execute_jsp._jspService(execute_jsp.java:63)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:98)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:331)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:321)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:257)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:269)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:188)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:213)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:172)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:117)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:108)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:174)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:873)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11BaseProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.processConnection(Http11BaseProtocol.java:665)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.PoolTcpEndpoint.processSocket(PoolTcpEndpoint.java:528)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.LeaderFollowerWorkerThread.runIt(LeaderFollowerWorkerThread.java:81)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPool$ControlRunnable.run(ThreadPool.java:689)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:595)
```

Other information:

- I am using tomcat (in Eclipse) as my server
- The exception shows up in the browser and the eclipse console
- execute.jsp is a JSP

*It seems like there are many similar questions to this on SO.  I have read about 15 of them and tried various things however I think that my question has a different solution.  I can provide more information.*

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Rightclick your dynamic web project, go to *Properties > Deployment Assembly* and add the dependent projects there. This way they will end up as JAR in `/WEB-INF/lib`, exactly there where you want it to be.

[image: Eclipse Project Properties Deployment Assembly]

In Eclipse versions older than 3.5 you need to go to *Properties > Java EE Module Dependencies*.

#### See also:

- [ClassNotFoundException when using User Libraries in Eclipse build path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7005644/classnotfoundexception-when-using-user-libraries-in-eclipse-build-path/)
- [Difference between Deployment Assembly and J2EE Module Dependencies in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11126044/difference-between-deployment-assembly-and-j2ee-module-dependencies-in-eclipse/)

Comment: If it was already configured, you can remove the deploy paths and then re-add it. It should fix the dependency.

Answer (score 3):

The `NoClassDefFoundError` indicates that a class that was available during compilation is no longer available at runtime. Your problem is that the `com/myCompany/bulkadmin/cSDK/util/Login` class is available in the compilation classpath (in Eclipse via the Project reference you added to the build path) but not in the runtime classpath (Tomcat, which has no idea how to find this class).

You need to add the `BulkAdmin` project to the web-app class path when deployed on Tomcat as well.

One way to do this would be to export the `BulkAdmin` project as a JAR and put it into the `WEB-INF/lib` directory of your `JSPTesting` project.

Comment: Fixed the typo.  (just a typo in the question not the actual code).

Comment: Eclipse seems pretty well integrated with tomcat/jsp.  It seems strange that there is not a built-in mechanism to provide the compile time stuff at runtime as well.

Comment: See @BalusC's answer - I was not aware of that feature in the IDE :)

Comment: +1 Thanks for the help.  I wish I could also accept your answer.

Comment: No worries, glad to be of help :)